# Remove all files from another folder that exist in the Unversioned Files section in IntelliJ

Tags: version-control, intellij-13

I copied a folder from my old project to my new project. After initializing Git, I noticed many files from the parent directory appearing in Unversioned Files. I wanted to remove all of them.

Answer (score 0):

After searching, I found a solution to resolve the issue.
I opened **vcs.xml** in the **.idea** folder, then removed all mapping tags, keeping only "**mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="Git"**"

. Afterward, I refreshed, and it was done.